# How to insert multiple data using relation?

Tags: php

**Controller**

```
public function AddPost(Request $request)
{
    Post::create($request->all());
    // PostImage::create();
    return Redirect::to('Post');
}
```

Also i have added Relation

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostImage');
    }
}
```

**`PostImage` model**

```
class PostImage extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

I have one form where i adding post title ,post content and selecting multiple images. My question is how I can store multiple images along with post id in post_images table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aptly-named `createMany()` method on the relation:

```
// Create post
$post = Post::create($request->except('images'));

// Create post images
foreach ($request->get('images') as $images) {
    $post->images()->create(compact('images'));
}
```

Comment: Hi it wil not work .it wil only add post id in image table not image .only single row wil add

Comment: @vision Have you set your columns to be fillable?

Comment: Ya. If i remove file input name array then it wil insert row with image

Comment: @vision I think I may have put a typo. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: @ Martin Bean.no this code even not inserting record to image table.i think i need loop

Comment: @vision You don’t need a loop. What does the `images` look like in your request object? Use `dd($request->get('images'))` to find out.

Comment: @vision Updated answer in response.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
Post::create($request->all())->images()->create([$request->get('images')]);
```

Comment: .thank you.i have multiple images i want to store each image as row

Comment: @vision i think it work, it works similar to `createMany()`

Comment: Hi its not working ..it produces single row with post id in images table.no image nor multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

as already post before... have you tried using the *saveMany* method? Actually, you can use it like this in an easy way.

The example in the Laravel Documentation speaks by itself.

You can use the simple *save* method to save a single instance.

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

$post = App\Post::find(1);

$comment = $post->comments()->save($comment);
```

If you have many instances of the "many" part of the relation, you can use saveMany().

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->saveMany([
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']),
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'Another comment.']),
]);
```

Both methods will automatically set the *post_id* value. If you want to set it manually you should get the *post_id* you need and then set it manually like this.

```
$comment->post_id = $yourDesiredPostId;
```

... and, finally, save as usual.

```
$comment->save();
```

**Note:** I used the Laravel Documentation example, but all you have to do here is to change names and classes. The mechanism is always the same.

Hope it helps.

Comment: .i am using single form where i am using some data in Post Model and multiple images in Post image table

Comment: the principle is always the same... first of all create your post, than you can attach to it multiple images using _save_ or _saveMany_ starting from the _images()_ relationship :)