# How to save multiple file name to database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Here is my code:

**ProductController.php**

```
$this->validate($request, [ 'name' => 'required', 'size' => 'required', 'color' => 'required', 'description' => 'required', 'category' => 'required', 'images' => 'required', ]);

    $id = [];
    $a = [];   

    for($i = 0; $i < count($input['images']); $i++){
      $name = rand(1,1000).'.'.$input['images'][$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $path = $input['images'][$i]->move('products/images', $name);

      $images->name = $name;
      $images->path = $path;

      $images->save();

      $a[] = $name;    
    }

    $d = Product::create($input);
    $d->category()->attach($request->get('category'));

    $x = [];

    for($j = 0; $j < count($a); $j++){
        $x = $images->where('name', '=', $a[$j])->get();
        // $x[] = $a[$j];
    }

    dd($x);
    // $d->images()->attach($x);
```

**Images.php**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Images extends Model { protected $table = 'images';

protected $fillable = ['name','path'];

public function product()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_images', 'pro_id', 'img_id');
}
}
```

**Product.php**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model { protected $table = 'product';

protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'size', 'color'];

public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'product_category', 'pro_id', 'cat_id');
}

public function images()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Images', 'product_images', 'pro_id', 'img_id');
}
}
```

**Schema**

```
Schema::create('images', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('product_images', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('pro_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('img_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('pro_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('product')
              ->onUpdate('cascade')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('img_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('images')
              ->onUpdate('cascade')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['pro_id', 'img_id']);
});
```

Now how can I attach multiple images with product ? Please give me the solution and if it needs to change anything please let me know. Thank you.....

I have updated to this code

```
 $d = Product::create($input);
        $d->category()->attach($request->get('category'));

        $a = [];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($input['images']); $i++){
          $name = rand().'.'.$input['images'][$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $path = $input['images'][$i]->move('products/images', $name);

          $images->name = $name;
          $images->path = $path;

          $images->save();

          $a[] = $images->id;

        }

        dd($a);

        $d->images()->sync($a);
```

Now how can I attach multiple images with product ? I am getting only the last image id. But it should be a array of id of 2 or more images IDs. Please give me the solution and if it needs to change anything please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to do that. The easier one is using relationships methods and then *save()*.

Here's an example from the Laravel documentation.

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

$post = App\Post::find(1);

$comment = $post->comments()->save($comment);
```

If you have many instances of the "many" part of the relation, you can use *saveMany()*.

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->saveMany([
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']),
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'Another comment.']),
]);
```

This solution above should be perfect for your needs.

Also, I suggest you to rename your models using the singular. Not *Images*, but *Image*. It will be more easier working with conventions.

More info here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

**EDIT**

About your situation.

First of all, I would move the

```
$d = Product::create($input);
```

right before the *for* cycle. After the *Product* creation, I would simply do, in your *for* cycle, this:

```
$d = Product::create($input);
$imagesIdsArray = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($input['images']); $i++){
    $name = rand(1,1000).'.'.$input['images'][$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $input['images'][$i]->move('products/images', $name);

    $images = new Image;

    $images->name = $name;
    $images->path = $path;

    $images->save();

    $imagesIdsArray[] = $images->id;
}

$d->images()->sync($imagesIdsArray);
```

By doing this you automatically set-up your relationship.

That

```
$d->images()->sync($imagesIdsArray);
```

is the key passage.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am saving multiple images to a table. Now how can I attach each image with product as my code style ? Please help me to find out.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show me what's your tables structure? Thanks

Comment: @Francesco Malatesta.i am also looking for same answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478680/how-to-insert-multiple-data-using-relation-in-laravel

Comment: Hi, @vision, you should be able to save multiple related records using the _saveMany_ method :) as I already wrote in the post. Let me know if you have some issues using it.

Comment: @can you post in my question

Comment: @FrancescoMalatesta I have added the schema.

Comment: Oh wait, you have a ManyToMany relationship here. In that case, you should use other methods as _attach()_, _detach()_ and the great method _sync()_ that does everything for you, starting from a simple ids array. [Take a look here to get more info about it](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Please see my controller and let me know how I can get the ID of Images. It will help me a lot. @FrancescoMalatesta

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `bfdbx_product_images` (`img_id`, `pro_id`) values (1, 1)) This is I am getting. Man I hanged up. Please me :( @FrancescoMalatesta

Comment: Probably you already tried to save the image before... have you cleaned up your database before going forward and try this new method?

Comment: yes totally cleaned up. the problem is same value like (2,2), (3,3) I think

Comment: My fault. The other topic confused me :) see my new edit. I removed the previous one.

Comment: NO bro it's getting only the last image ID :'

`$imagesIdsArray[] = $images->id;

( array:3 [▼
  0 => 3
  1 => 3
  2 => 3
]`

Comment: You forgot the $images = new Images; :) or you will edit the same image every time!

Comment: Bro can I have your skype ID please ? It's solved. I want to get in touch with you.